# "Kasten" an Metalldetektor

Tags: single-word-request

Einige tragbare Metalldetektoren, wie der unten abgebildete, besitzen am oberen Ende der Stange, wo sie um den Unterarm geschnallt wird, einen "Kasten", der gelegentlich an den Rumpf einer handgeführten Bohrmaschine oder anderer Elektrowerkzeuge erinnert.

Wie heißt dieser Teil eines solchen Gerätes?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bei Geräten und Maschinen nennt man einen solchen »Kasten« oft

> Gehäuse

Beispiel aus dem Duden-Bildwörterbuch von 1992:

[image: Gehäuse eines Gerätes]

Ein verwandter Begriff ist die

> Verkleidung
>
> ([Duden:](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Verkleidung#Bedeutung2b) *die Verkleidung [der Maschine] entfernen*)

Comment: Danke. Hab zwischenzeitlich aus diese Abbildung gefunden, die deinen Vorschlag bestätigt: https://www.detector-scout.de/custom/images/03_tesoro_cortes/07_cortes_mit_text.jpg